# .htaccess redirect (need help quickly please)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Today i noticed that all my links are not redirected the right way so i am loosing my link juice.

Can someone help me out.

What i did was this in my .htaccess file

redirect 301 /tag/my-old-website-link http://www.mynewsite.com/tag/my-old-website-link

Now what happens is that the new link becomes http://www.mynewsite.comtag/my-old-website-link

So after the .com the / is missing.

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: i found a part of the solution.
I also had this redirect
/ http://www.mynewsite.com

After deleting this part everything worked fine.

Now my question is how to redirect the homepage the right way also

Answer (score 0):

I found out :-)

To only redirect the homepage i have added this to my .htaccess file:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Now every extra line is redirected correctly